# props is defined, but below undefined

Tags: reactjs

Props defined in state but below it is undefined

Hi I'm having a small problem with my code. I wanted to call a Parent function from a Child but the error says can't read properties
of undefined. I changed it then to just log this.props but same error. The confusing part is it is defined in state where i assing
this.props.inputValue to inputValue and i can use it there and it works, but in the function message which is
called by a button press it is undefined.

CHILD

```
class Search extends React.Component {

    state = {
        loading: true,
        inputValue : this.props.inputValue
    }

    message(){
        console.log(this.props)
        // this.props.sendMessage("HI")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row mb-3">
                
                <div className="col-auto mb-3">
                    
                    <label className="col-form-label text-center">Suche:</label>
                    
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-3 mb-3">
                    
                    <input id="Input" className="form-control" type="text" 
                    value={this.state.inputValue}
                    onChange={event => this.updateInputValue(event)}/>
                    
                </div>

                <div className="col-md-auto mb-3">
                    
                    <button id="add" onClick={this.message} className="form-control btn btn-success" >➕</button>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
    updateInputValue(event) {
        this.setState({
            inputValue : event.target.value
        })
    }
}
export default Search;
```

PARENT

```
class App extends Component {
    state ={
        title: "Benutzerdatensuche",
        inputValue: "Suche",
        value: "0"
    }

    render(){
    return ( 
        <div className = "App" >
            <Header title={this.state.title} />
            <Search inputValue={this.state.inputValue} sendMessage={this.message.bind(this)}/>
            <InfoBox />
            {this.state.value}
        </div>
    )}

    message(text){
        console.log(text)
    }
}
```

I really cant understand why it won't work

Comment: Looking at your "PARENT" component, you seem to already be aware of the need to bind your class methods when passing them as props. Why didn't you do the same with the class method in your "CHILD" component? That's your problem right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using a class component, the `onClick` handler (`this.message`) needs to be bound to the class AKA `this`. There are two common ways to achieve the binding.

**Using .bind**

```jsx
<button
  id="add"
  onClick={this.message.bind(this)}
  className="form-control btn btn-success"
>
  ...
</button>
```

Notice the `.bind(this)`

**With arrow function**

```jsx
<button
  id="add"
  onClick={() => this.message()}
  className="form-control btn btn-success"
>
  ...
</button>
```

This is because of the way the context of `this` works in JavaScript (not specific to React). See the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html which state:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that method.